# Connection between Directional and Omni-directional outdoor Antennas

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, wireless-access-point, antenna

i want to setup a small network, i have more than basic knowledge of networking but i have some questions that i couldn't find any answer for them till now. so i have two stations with a distance of 0.8 Mile.

at station 1 i'm gonna use a 12dbi omni-directional antenna ([product link](http://www.tp-link.com/en/products/details/?categoryid=2474&model=TL-ANT2412D)). i'm gonna put it 6 meters above the ground and use a cable [like this](http://www.tp-link.com/en/products/details/?categoryid=2475&model=TL-ANT24EC6N) to connect it to a home router.
at station 2 i'm gonna use a directional antenna (tp-link 2.4GHz High Power Wireless Outdoor CPE TL-WA5210G) directed to the station 1.

my question is that is the connectivity between a directional and omni-directional antenna, with clear LOS possible? if so then what about multiple directional antennas with one omni-directional antenna? 
Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it works. When you have multiple clients you use an omnidirectional antenna at the access point (or sector antennas if you need more range and/or bandwidth) and directional antennas at clients.

When an antenna is more directional you get more range (you concentrate your radio power in one direction) and less interference (you only listen at what's coming from one direction) but you need to be more accurate at pointing in the right direction.

Comment: so considering the fact that the omni antenna is a 12dbi antenna with a range (around 0.3 mile), does the directional 12dbi AP (2km range) need to point exactly do the omni antenna?

Comment: or can it be in any direction providing that it's in the omni antenna's coverage radius?

Comment: It needs to be pointed towards the AP. See the edit of the answer.

Answer (score 0):

The omnidirectional antenna needs to fall within the directional antenna's beam-width.

It's just like aiming a directional TV antenna, point it at the station's transmitter tower for maximum signal.

Otherwise your directional antenna will be dealing with multi-path from reflected signals, not the main direct omni station signal and listening quite intently to everything else in it's beamwidth on the same channel, but not your omni base station leading to much interference, degradation of signal and poor channel throughput.

Comment: sorry that i can't vote up! But Thank you for the useful information, i'll definitely consider all of them.